# Cannot flash or connect to my Nucleo board (STM32F446) anymore

Tags: telnet

for some reason I cannot flash my [Nucleo (STM32F446) board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f446re.html) anymore. It used to work well... I got the following message:

```
openocd -f ./cfg/openocd.cfg -c "program ./build/ch.elf verify reset" -c "shutdown"
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v34 API v2 SWIM v25 VID 0x0483 PID 0x374B
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.247800
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)
in procedure 'program' 
in procedure 'init' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 506
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked

Makefile:210: recipe for target 'flash' failed
make: *** [flash] Error 1
```

Also when I am issuing:

```
telnet localhost 4444
```

I get:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

When I plug my Nucleo board I can see its build version etc. Strange.

Edit: LD1 is solid when the board is plugged. I think it should normally be blinking red.

Comment: Sadly, it might be dead. Check cables and connections and all of the basics. But cheap boards are cheap for a reason.

Comment: Can it be dead if I can see the device on my computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used st link utility which is a windows program provided by st.

It allowed me to erase and reflash the mcu using SWD interface.

The reason behind my problem was I ticked the *Set all free pins as analog to optimize power consumption* before generating my project files with CubeMX. It actually broke the boot config as BOOT0 pin was set to analog.

TLDR: don't tick **Set all free pins as analog** in CubeMX